# Recover terminated EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

title says it all. I inadvertently terminated an EC2 Instance and desperately need to restart it/relaunch it!!!
Any help? It would be disastrous if I had to start all over!! Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: This is not a solution, but rather a tip. There is a feature in AWS called 'termination protection'. If you switch that on for an ec2 instance, then you can't inadvertantly terminate instances.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically it goes like this:

- Your machine is gone, you cannot restart, you need to **create** a new instance
- all the data you had on an instance store volume are gone (you cannot recover those)
- If you had EBS Volume attached and you had setting enable for 'delete on termination' the latest data are gone. You can recover if you have a snapshot from this volume.
- If you had EBS Volume attached without flag for 'delete on termination' you can recover those data

So what you can do:

- check your snapshots and Volumes in the ec2 console. If you have no snapshot/volumes, you cannot recover anything
- if you have root volumes,

  - make a snapshot of those you want to recover
  - from the snapshot, make an image
  - from the ami, launch a new instance for the specific image you've just created
- if you dont have root volumes

  - create volumes from snapshot if you have any snapshot you need to recover data
  - create a new ec2 instance
  - attach and mount the volumes to the new instance
  - read and backup your data

Comment: TL;DR: it's gone when it's terminated.

Comment: To confirm for anyone else wondering, even with an Enterprise support plan, once they're terminated there's nothing that can be done, even by AWS support engineers.

Comment: @FredericHenri I faced a [problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/1022282/when-stopping-ec2-instance-it-starts-again-automatically-listed-separately-pre) today which as pointed out by a user was related to autoscaling so I solved by setting the desired and minimum value of instances to 0 in autoscaling group. Then I stopped my instance, it said stopped there but later it was changed to terminated. Although I panicked and when changed back the autoscaling setting, it worked but why it was terminated even when stopped?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I am facing the same issue now. I was able to see the terminated instance but it is now gone. Where did you find your terminated instance?

Comment: surprising they don't tell you to confirm the termination....i thought it was just like a force stop cause stop was taking awhile

Comment: This happened to me when I deleted an auto scaling group. Apparently that terminated any ec2 instances that are members. Remarkable.