# Need backup of terminated AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I accidentally terminated one aws instance. is there any way to get backup of AWS terminated instance?. I couldn't find the volume attached with instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover terminated EC2 Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103039/recover-terminated-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the Amazon EBS disk volume is no longer visible in your console, then it is gone and cannot be recovered.

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance, you can specify a **Delete on Termination** flag that indicates whether to delete the EBS volume(s) when the instance is terminated. If you wish to keep the disks after instances are terminated, make sure you do *not* have this option selected.